# What is the meaning of "I'm aware it rhymes"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does it mean ?

> See, that's why he's the genius!
>  It even rhymes!
>  **I'm aware it rhymes.**

It was in [Lorax 2012](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1482459/)

Comment: What did you find when you looked up ***aware*** in the dictionary? (I assume that's the sticking-point; if it isn't, please edit the question to say exactly what is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's provide a little more context (from http://lovin-the-lorax.wikispaces.com/Part+1+Chapter+4:

Mr. O’Hare: So in other words, the more smog in the **sky**; the more people will **buy**.

Salesman 2: See, that’s why he’s the genius! It even rhymes!

Mr. O’Hare: I’m aware it rhymes.

The words "buy" and "sky" rhyme. "See, that's why he's the genius!" is refering to the inspiration that more smog will increase sales, with the fact that this idea was expressed in rhyme suggesting an additional sense of verbal style (and hence, a further sign of genius).

Finally, Mr O'Hare points out that he knows that he created a rhyme.

Comment: Thnx a lot ...  1++